# Динамическое создание PictureBox N-го количества

Tags: c#, winforms

В общем, есть папка с изображениями, при выборе этой папки на форме нужно создать `PictureBox` и в каждый `PictureBox` поместить изображение, т.е - получается как бы "страница" с изображениями. Только нужно предусмотреть, чтобы `PictureBox` не выходил за рамки самой формы, может можно поместить в какой-нибудь "контейнер" у которого появляется скролл?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.

Скриншот для визуального примера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте ListView и помещайте в него картинки
[Должно подтолкнуть на решение задачи](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366294/listview-in-c-sharp-with-images)

Comment: @ViktorKozenko, первый раз картинки загрузило, все последующие разы выбрасывает исключение `System.OutOfMemoryException (недостаточно памяти)`, из-за чего может быть, не подскажете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался! Проблема с исключением `OutOfMemoryException` была из-за того, что в папке с изображениями присутствовал скрытый файл `Thumbs.db`. Можете удалить вручную, а можно игнорировать это исключение.

Создайте `FlowLayoutPanel` поставьте `AutoScroll = true` и `Dock = Fill`.

Код:

```
List<PictureBox> picturebox = new List<PictureBox>();
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"путь к папке с изображениями");
var recentpics = directoryInfo.GetFiles().ToList();
var y = 10;

foreach (var file in recentpics)
{
    var pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.Location = new Point(picturebox.Count * 120 + 20, y);
    pb.Size = new Size(100, 120);
    try 
    {
        pb.Image = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException) { continue; }
    pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
    picturebox.Add(pb);
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В качестве контейнера лучше использовать FlowLayoutPanel и помещать туда эскизы, вызвав у Image GetThumbnailImage.  System.OutOfMemoryException может возникнуть, когда длина файла с картинкой равна 0 (ну или в файле содержится не картинка, это не берусь утверждать)